# Chain Multiple Reduce in ChainReducer

Tags: mapreduce

I have are requirement to chain a map reduce job like this using map reduce chaining. [Map --> Reduce --> Map --> Reduce -- > Map --> Map]. Looking at Javadocs of ChainReducer I get the feeling that this is not possible. (It says it supports the form of [MAP+ / REDUCE MAP*] which is not exactly what I want.) Is there a way to achieve this using Map Reduce API?

Comment: Would you be willing to do two MapReduce jobs?  The first one does your first M->R; the second uses the ChainReducer to do M->R->M->M.

Comment: I would rather like to use a single map reduce chain for this since intermediate results are not required.

Comment: @RayToal I have a case where I am doing M1>R->M2->M3. I have done the chaining properly and but the chain is not executing like it should. The problem is that M2 and M3 are running at the same time rather than one after the other. Could you please help?

Comment: I haven't touched Hadoop since 2012 so probably not. Try asking a separate question on StackOverflow and someone should be able to jump in and help. Cheers.